# How can I extract email content from an EML file using Node.js while excluding any quoted text?

Tags: javascript

I am currently using Mailparser to extract values from emails, but I've encountered a challenge. Some of the emails contain replies that are enclosed within quotes. To address this issue, I attempted to use the 'node-email-reply-parser' library to remove the replies. However, I encountered a limitation with this library as it only supports plain text without maintaining the email formatting. I'm looking for a solution that not only removes the replies within quotes but also preserves the formatting of the email content.

I attempted to use the following regex pattern: (/On\s.*?wrote:\s*|((?:(?!</?blockquote>).)*)</blockquote>/g, '') to replace HTML blockquote tags. However, I encountered an issue with this regex—it doesn't effectively filter out nested blockquote tags.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.